# Backgrounds getting removed on mobile view

Tags: css, wordpress

I added some backgrounds to a few different divs — both image backgrounds and just solid color. When I look at the mobile view, all the backgrounds disappear and it's just white, meaning some images and text can't be seen. Is there something I'm missing in the CSS that's causing this?

The website is based on the WordPress Twenty Seventeen template, and can be seen at [echomartin.com/angie-wiechmann/](http://echomartin.com/angie-wiechmann/)

[Child theme CSS](http://echomartin.com/angie-wiechmann/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/style.css)

[Twenty Seventeen CSS](http://echomartin.com/angie-wiechmann/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen/style.css)

Comment: Where's the css code?

Comment: Edited to include links to the CSS documents

Comment: Giving links to the css is not enough, you should paste them here. (Only codes related to the problem)

Comment: The problem is that I didn't know what codes were related to the problem. My backgrounds were disappearing with mobile view, which I didn't think I had put into my code. The problem could have been literally anywhere in my CSS, hence why I didn't just paste a nice little snippet of code. The problem has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code to display background images is included in conditional CSS which is only used on wider screens. e.g. in the TwentySeventeen Child style.css you have this:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 30em) {
    .book {
        background-image: url("http://echomartin.com/angie-wiechmann/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/seawater-s.jpg");
        ...
    }
}
```

This means that the background image will only show on screens with a minimum width of 30ems. If you want this style to apply to all screen widths, just move it outside of the @media block.

Comment: It is also located outside of the media screen, which you'll find above the one you looked at. All the background code is outside of the media screens. I included a copy of the code in the media screen to try to force it to appear, but it didn't work. I do understand that the child theme CSS could definitely use some organization.

Comment: I think the main problem is that your brackets don't all match up. Where you have `/*Full screen laptop/computer screen view*/
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {` there is no closing brace so I think everything after this it's trying to interpret conditionally

Comment: That was it! Didn't realize I had that extra line in there for that media screen. Highlighted some other issues with the mobile view, but fixed the background problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't found any **`}`** for

```
/*Full screen laptop/computer screen view*/
@media screen and (min-width: 48em) {
```